# PHP storing returned oauth_secret

Tags: php, oauth

Jumping from twitter's api to Tumblr's was supposed to be easy. But it turns out they don't actually implement oauth in the same way. Although Twitter returns a oauth_tokensecret, it doesn't require that you use it to get an access token. Tumblr does. Now that is creating an extra step, since when the user is redirected to the Tumblr login screen the php session is lost.

Is the primary practice to store this returned secret token in a server side database or in a client side cookie for retrieval?

**EDIT 1**

Using cookie I hit a hiccup.

```
Step 1. Send credential tokens of app.
Step 2. Receive as POST oauth_token and oauth_token_secret from Tumblr.
Step 3. Redirect user to Tumblr login using the oauth_token from Step 2.
Step 4. After login, Tumblr redirect back to my site with oauth_verifier.
Step 5. I submit the oauth_token_secret from step 2 and oauth_verifier from step 4. 
Step 6. I receive access_token to users info.
```

Step 6 is failing because I'm losing access to the oauth_token_secret from step 1 during step 3. When I redirect to Tumblr's login page both my session and cookie superglobals are cleared.

Code for step 3.

```
//checked and verified that $tkns['oauth_token_secret'] has data
$_SESSION['secret']=$tkns['oauth_token_secret'];
setcookie('tumblr_secret',$tkns['oauth_token_secret'], time()+604800, '/');
session_write_close();
header("Location: http://www.tumblr.comoauthauthorize?oauth_token=".$tkns['oauth_token']); 
exit();
```

Code on return from login

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['secret'])){
    echo "it's all gone!";
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['tumblr_secret'])){
     echo "it's all gone!";
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Got watch those domains. all pages had www. preceding the link instead of one. SO simple.

Comment: You should store in session for all sites, Twitter if I am not misstaken generates a key that you can use anytime and you can store in a DB. After the Tumblr login the API should redirect to your page and you have the session variables

Comment: no, steps are: 1. submit app credential tokens->receive POST oauth_token and oauth_token _secret.  2. Use received oauth_token to redirect to Tumblr login.  3. After login Tumblr returns GET oauth_token and oauth_verifier. 4. submit oauth_token_secret from step 1 and oauth_verifier from step 3.    But the redirect from step 2 destroys php session.?

Answer (score 0):

You may store the returned secret token in a cookie or session, so that it can be easily accessed, when possibly later requested (client side) from Twitter, after the Tumblr login.